# Give nested query an alias

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a query like this

```
SELECT m.title
FROM Movie AS M
WHERE
(SELECT MAX(r.stars)
 FROM rating AS r
WHERE r.mID = M.mID);
```

I want to show MAX(R.stars) in the result set, how do I do that?

Comment: you want to add an alias to MAX(R.stars)? i dont understand

Comment: You have already asked this on dba.stackexchange.com [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65544/problem-in-nested-query)

Comment: Because the community on stackoverflow is more faster than the DBA community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this !

```
SELECT m.title, MAX(r.stars)
FROM Movie AS M
 inner join rating AS r
on r.mID = M.mID
group by m.title
```

or like the old school method

```
  SELECT m.title, MAX(r.stars)
    FROM Movie AS M,rating AS r
    where r.mID = M.mID
    group by m.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
SELECT m.title, (SELECT MAX(r.stars) FROM rating AS r WHERE r.mID = M.mID) As MaxStarts
FROM Movie AS M
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to show MAX(R.stars) in the result set, then a simpler approach would be to use a **LEFT JOIN**:

```
  SELECT m.Title, MAX(r.stars)
  FROM Movie m
  LEFT JOIN rating r
  ON M.mID = r.mID
```

No need to use alias.